# Micro Frontend For Flutter Mobile

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, architecture, micro-frontend

Is there any way to make microfrontend with Flutter Mobile. We have a big team and we wanna to use microfrontend with Flutter. I am not sure can we handle a big project with monolith application. We have goals to make a super app which is merging 8 application in one. I do not want to use webview. I want to make it with dart language.